# How to call function and retrieve two returns in Arduino or C?

Tags: c, arduino

I made a function, and I want to retrieve two returns, not a single return such as this example:

```
long Conv(double num){      
    long a,b;
    a = floor(num);
    b = num * pow(10,6) - a * pow(10,6);

    return a;
    return b;
}
```

When I call the function

```
long a = Conv(30.233456);
```

the question is: how do I retrieve `b`?

Comment: Return a `struct` with both values in it, or have your function take pointers to `a` and `b` and write the values there.

Comment: Just use `floor(num)` to get `a` (if you need it outside the function), and return `b` from your function.  If you only want to calculate `a` once, pass it into the function as a parameter.

Comment: why don't you just make two different functions?

Comment: @Zupoman: `Floor` is *already* a different function.

Answer (score 4):

You can't return two times at once.

You could pass b to your function by reference.

```
yourfunction( long a , long* b )
{    
    *b = a + 10;
    //more code

return a;
}

a = yourfunction(a , &b );
```

Comment: your code works perfectly..

Answer (score 3):

**You can't return more than one value from a function in C.** Either return a `struct`, or pass by reference and modify in the function.

Example 1: `struct`

```
struct ab {
  long a;
  long b;
}

struct ab Conv(double num) {
  struct ab ab_instance;

  ab_instance.a = floor(num);
  ab_instance.b = num * pow(10,6) - a * pow(10,6);

  return ab_instance;
}
```

Example 2: `pass b by reference`

```
long Conv(double num, long& b) {
  long a;
  a = floor(num);
  b = num * pow(10,6) - a * pow(10,6);

  return a;
}
```

Comment: Pass by *reference* you mean.

Comment: You need to have `struct ab ab_instance`.

Comment: @meyumer i have used the second example : pass by reference  and i call the function  :  long b;
      long  a=Conv(30.233456,&b);

Comment: @meyumer :  invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'long int&' from a temporary of type 'long int*'

Comment: @meyumer  error: in passing argument 2 of 'long int Conv(double, long int&)'

Comment: `a=Conv(30.233456,&b)` calling syntax is not correct. you should call it by: `a=Conv(30.233456,b)`. Where `a` and `b` are initialized prior to the call by: `long a; long b;`.

Comment: @meyumer If you could explain what is going on, we could understand better! Could you please explain your code?

Answer (score 1):

Armin kind of answered it, but here is some sample code:

```
int get_both(int* b) {
    a = 0;
    *b = 1;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: long Conv(double num){
  
    long a,b;
    a = floor(num);
   *b = num * pow(10,6) - a * pow(10,6);
    
    return a;    
}

Comment: i tried something like this but gives me error

Comment: Where is the error, and what is it?